# Proper word for "all type of rooms / accommodations"?

Tags: expressions

I'm working on this app and right now it has a common taxonomy called "hotel". However, this app can work with hotels, chains of hotels, apartments, rooms, cabins, guesthouses and anything you could think of, so "Hotel" is a very inaccurate taxonomy name, something proven with the first small test we ran, all subjects gave different answers.

However, can't find a proper taxonomy name that covers all these instances yet is easy to understand by anyone using the app. I thought of "Rooms" but then we face the opposite problem: what happens with owners of hotel chains that have hotels or apartments as secondary level taxonomies?

So far, the closest I can get is "Accommodations", but again, testing shown it's too ambiguous. Lodging has been rejected due to its *short term* connotations

Any ideas on the proper wording for this?

Comment: Are all of your examples procured for a limited period of time?  Could you use "nights"?

Comment: Kristina, periods of time are indeed limited, but the limits can go from 1 night to a couple years. While a great idea *nights* will be kind of difficult for long periods. Besides, the location itself is important since it's a taxonomy, so something like (whaterver_word) would be the category and then I'd have sub-categories such as hotel, apartment, condos and so on

Comment: I haven't researched a proper answer, but most of the dives and palaces I've stayed in lately (US, through 2015) use the term "amenities" in a very broad sense to cover the page that lists rooms, suites, meeting rooms, gyms, saunas and just about everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the noun:

**Sites**

:A place that is used for a particular activity [Webster's]

The adjective is a bit trickier. I would pick:

**Hosting**

:The process of one that receives or entertains guests socially, commercially or officially [Webster's]

I speak from personal experience that the highly varied "lodging" company AirBNB uses "host" quite successfully.

Thus, *Hosting sites.* The only problem I see is potential confusion regarding "websites," but within context should be obvious.

You could then subdivide from there into hotels, apartments, rooms, short term, long term, etc.